# Django, Docker, postgreSQL Accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I I am using Docker and I got this message :

`Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Here is my docker-compose :

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/web/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 3000:3000
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
      - POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I precise I change the value of the parameter 'HOST' in the settings.py to db but it does not work I still have this error.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Which command, in which environment, produces that error message?  How are you actually configuring the database location?

Comment: `Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? ` seems to be an adequate question. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your old postgres server is shutdown properly.
you can delete old docker images by

> docker rmi -f  $(docker images -a -q)

> docker container prune

then run your docker-compose

> docker-compose up --build

Hope this will work. I got similar error because I was having another postgresql running over my localhost.
You can also install postgres app which will help your db to force start and force shutdown your postgres server.